# How do I include the blank/space in regular expression pattern in VB Script?

Tags: regex, string, search, text, vbscript

How do I include the space in regular expression pattern in VB Script?

For this code:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set file = objFSO.OpenTextFile("sample.txt" , ForReading)  
Const ForReading = 1

Dim re
Set re = new regexp 
re.Pattern = "(\w+?[(]\w+?[)];)"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global = True

Dim line
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    line = file.ReadLine
    For Each m In re.Execute(line)
       Wscript.Echo m.Submatches(0)
    Next
Loop
```

With sample.txt file:

```
object();
object(string);
```

I want to echo this:

```
object();
object(string);
```

Instead of only this:

```
object(string);
```

Comment: assuming `[ ]` would do the trick, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your pattern as follows:

```
re.Pattern = "(\w+?[(]\w*?[)];)"
'                       ^ use * instead of + here
```

Using the `*` (zero-or-more) quantifier instead of the `+` (one-or-more) quantifier will let you match both of these:

```
object();
object(string);
```